# pybind11 equivalent of boost::python::extract?

Tags: boost-python, pybind11

I am considering port of a complex code from boost::python to pybind11, but I am puzzled by the absence of something like `boost::python::extract<...>().check()`. I read `pybind11::cast<T>` can be used to extract c++ object from a `py::object`, but the only way to check if the cast is possible is by calling it and catching the exception when the cast fails. Is there something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isinstance` will do the job ([doc](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=isinstanc#_CPPv210isinstance6handle)) :

```
namespace py = pybind11;
py::object  obj =  ...
if (py::isinstance<py::array_t<double>>(obj))
{
    ....
} 
else if (py::isinstance<py::str>(obj))
{
   std::string val = obj.cast<std::string>();
   std::cout << val  << std::endl;
} 
else if (py::isinstance<py::list>(obj))  
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Follow-up question: how do I use this to test if the object is a Python representation of one of my classes (that was exposed to Python via pybind11)?

Comment: @LarryGritz idem : `py::isinstance<MyCustomClass>(obj)` .